# Compute $\text{sinc}^{2}(x) \star \text{sinc}^{2}(x)$ without using fourier transforms

Tags: integration

Compute $\text{sinc}^{2}(x) \star \text{sinc}^{2}(x)$  where $\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\text{sin}(\pi x)}{(\pi x)}$ and $\star$ denotes convolution.

I am able to solve this using fourier transform - $\text{sinc}^{2}(x)$ and $\text{tri}(x)$ are fourier pairs. To convolve, I multiplied the FT (i.e. $\text{tri}(x) \cdot \text{tri}(x)$) and used Wolfram-Alpha to compute the inverse FT.

However, I am not able to solve it as a straight convolution integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{sinc}^{2}(x) \text{sinc}^{2}(y-x)\,{\rm d}x$$

Any help in solving this without FT?

Comment: Do you know complex analysis / contour integration or are you looking for solving it with just standard calculus methods?

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}^{2}(x) \operatorname{sinc}^{2}(y-x) dx$$
Let $x\to-\pi x \implies dx \to -\pi dx$
$$=\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}^{2}(-\pi x) \operatorname{sinc}^{2}(y+\pi x) dx$$
$$=\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}^{2}(\pi x) \operatorname{sinc}^{2}[\pi(x-(-y/\pi))] dx$$
It now seems that we could almost apply $\color{blue}{(31)}$ from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html), which states that
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\operatorname{sinc}(\pi x) \operatorname{sinc}^{2}[\pi(x-y)] dx = \operatorname{sinc}(\pi x)$$

Comment: Perhaps an argument similar to the fact that the sum over $\text{sinc}(x)$ and $\text{sinc}^2(x)$ are related could be used here? Just an idea. My guess is that I can find a proof for $\color{blue}{(31)}$ much more easily, since it appears in the literature. Perhaps the proofs will correlate a bit, and so some inspiration could be drawn from the proof of $\color{blue}{(31)}$?

Comment: Winther, I am minimally aware of contour integration, though by no means I am good at it. I know sinc(x) decays at infinity. But sinc(i x) doesn't. So I can't think of the usual infinite semi-circle method (as it is non zero at infinity on imaginary axis). Any hints on choosing a suitable contour?

Comment: Brevan, (31) only refers to convolution of 2 sinc functions (not a sinc and a sinc^2 as you have pasted here).

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of a [triangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function) 
$$\mathrm{tri}(x)=\begin{cases}
1-|x|,&|x|<1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
is $\mathrm{sinc}^2(f)$.

Using duality property, the Fourier transform of $\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)$ is $\mathrm{tri}(f)$ (except a normalization factor depending on the definition of the Fourier Transform).

Using convolution theorem,
$$\mathcal{F}\{\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)\star\mathrm{sinc}^2(x)\}=(\mathrm{tri}(f))^2=\begin{cases}
1+x^2-2|x|,&|x|<1\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I just noticed you look for solutions using methods other than FT! Maybe this answer is useful for others...